# Zend_Form user error value decode

Tags: php, mysql, forms, zend-framework, encoding

After a user fills in a form but does not fill a required field the form is returned with the element in question with the error message - all the fields previously filled are filled out again but the data being entered has `&amp;` instead of &.

How does zend populate a form that is submit and returned with user errors. How can i filter/run html_entity_decode on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Zend_Filter` with a callback on a particular method to filter your field.

From the [Zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html):

> ### Callback
>
> This filter allows you to use own methods in conjunction with
>   Zend_Filter. You don't have to create a new filter when you already
>   have a method which does the job.
>
> Supported options for Zend_Filter_Callback The following options are
>   supported for Zend_Filter_Callback:
>
> callback: This sets the callback which should be used.
>
> options: This property sets the options which are used when the
>   callback is processed

So basically, your element filter would look like this:

`$myElement->addFilter('Callback', array('callback' => array($this, 'myFilter')))`

And in the same class, you can create a method named `myFilter()` that takes a `$value` parameter.
 This function can `return html_entity_decode;` for example. You could also use an inline function using PHP 5.3+: `function($v){return(html_entity_decode($v);)}`.